# What is the difference between "f is monotone increasing at x" and "f is monotone increasing on a neighborhood of x"?

Tags: analysis

My understanding is that the statement "f is monotone increasing at $x$" means that there exists a neighborhood of $x$ such that $f(x_1) \leq f(x) \leq f(x_2)$ for all points $x_1, x_2$ in the neighborhood of $x$ where $x_1 < x_2$.

So how is this different from saying the statement "f is monotone increasing on a neighborhood of $x$"?

Can anyone perhaps provide an example of why these two statements are not equal, or perhaps some general intuition?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the function satisfies f(x_1)<f(x)<f(x_2) when x_1<x<x_2 but perhaps x is the only point in any neighborhood of x where this is true..

Comment: Consider f(x)={1/n if x=p/n (rational, positive), -1/n if x=-p/n (rational, negative), 0 otherwise} defined on [-1,1]. I'm not sure about your exact definitions for things though.

Comment: Thank you! First comment really explained it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function:

$f(x)=x\mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$.

Then the only point where $f$ is continuous is 0. Moreover, it's the only point where it's increasing (take any greater value than 0, then it's either equal to this value, either equal to 0, and the same for a negative value). However, a neighborhood of 0 will contain rationals and irrationals. Thus, the function will be sometimes equal to 0 (on irrationals) and sometimes non-zero (on rationals) so it's definitely not monotone on a neighborhood of 0.